# Embed NavigationController in Container View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to embed a Navigation Controller in a Container View using the Storyboard.  I add my Container View to my scene, delete the View Controller that it is automatically generated, and control-drag from the Container View to my Navigation Controller, creating a segue.

When I run the app in the simulator and transition to the scene containing the Container View, I get this exception:

2018-04-28 15:22:40.278627-0400 Woofr[8977:18656423] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView.'

If I run it as a test with just the original automatically generated View Controller in place, it works.  If I control-drag from the Container View to the Navigation Controller without deleting the automatically generated View Controller, the segue is replaced in the Storyboard, but I get the same exception when I run the app.

ETA full stack trace:

```
2018-04-28 15:44:22.748243-0400 Woofr[15437:18687945] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate 0x6040004756c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001078521e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010699a031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001078520b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001063bbb47 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000108cc2d56 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077f4e8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000108cc1700 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001089dc137 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001089dca64 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001089dcd81 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 175
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001089dd5d4 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000108a0ec6e -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 945
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000108a255e2 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 714
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000108a268cc -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000108c7ebd7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000108908808 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001045d161a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001045d582b _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010455c29f _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 343
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104589940 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 568
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010883334f _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 167
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000109198532 __handleEventQueueInternal + 6875
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077f4bb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077d94af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077d8a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077d830b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010cb86a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    27  UIKit                               0x00000001088390b7 UIApplicationMain + 159
    28  Woofr                               0x0000000100d34427 main + 55
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b050955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

ETA Settings Scene screen shot:

[image: Settings Scene]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `ViewController` class which contains the `containerView`, make sure to add `IBOutlet` for it

```swift
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
```

When you drag a `ContainerView` into a view and give it constraints, it creates a `ViewController` with a segue from that `ContainerView`.

Embed this destination `ViewController` in a `NavigationController` from

**Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller**

[image: Storyboard Image]

Comment: I control-dragged to add that but got the same exception.

Comment: value coding-compliant for the key containerView ??? or another view ?? post the new error

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I edited the question to include the full stack trace.

Comment: can you show a photo of storyboard ? with expanded views content

Comment: I added a screen shot of the Settings Scene.  There are a lot of scenes in the app -- in this case the only segues are back to the Log In screen and to the Navigation Controller.  The Navigation Controller is a standard container for a Table View that segues to a detail page for the items in the Table View.

Comment: make the segue from the the yellow icon of the setttingsVC not from a view inside it

Comment: How will that display the Navigation Controller inside the Container View?  All the examples I've seen say to drag from the Container View to the View Controller.

Comment: That was it, thank you!  It's not possible to embed a Navigation Controller directly into a Container View.  You have to add a segue to the first View Controller from the Container View then embed that VC in a Navigation Controller.

Comment: How can I embed the ContainerView with NavigationController programmatically? any idea?