# Swift - push & pop UIViewcontroller not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I am having problems with my `ViewControllers`. Does anyone know why that code is not working? The `print` function work...

**A to B**

```
    @IBAction func editButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let imageCollectionView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageCollectionVC") as! ImageCollectionViewController
    imageCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imageCollectionView, animated: true)
    print("editButtonTapped")
}



}

    extension ExampleViewController: ClassBDelegate {
            func childVCDidComplete( with image: UIImage?) {
                self.pickedImage = image!
            }
    }
```

**B to A**

```
 protocol ClassBDelegate {
    func childVCDidComplete(with image: UIImage?)
}

class ImageCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var delegate: ClassBDelegate?
var tappedImage = UIImage()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   tappedImage = images[indexPath.row]
   delegate?.childVCDidComplete(with: tappedImage)
   navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

That is my full project: https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist

ViewController A in my case is `ExampleViewController` and B is `ImageCollectionViewController`

***UPDATE***

that is my Storyboard:

`ImageViewController` is the right one and `ExampleViewController` is the one left to it.

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is supposed to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: nothing happens. Thats the problem

Comment: `editButtonTapped` should bring you to `ImageCollectionViewController` and tapping on a `cell` should bring you back to `ExampleViewController`

Comment: OK. So does `editButtonTapped` print "editButtonTapped"? If not, the button isn't hooked up. If so, the problem is you have no navigation controller so there is nowhere to push to.

Comment: yes it does and I tested `didSelectItemAt` as well and it gets called , thats what I dont get :(

Comment: is `self.navigationController` non-nil?  Set a breakpoint in `editButtonTapped` and step through - what is happening?

Comment: i checked it and it is `nil` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check navigationController instance in below line of code:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imageCollectionView, animated: true)
```

If `self.navigationController` is nil then you may have not embedded navigation controller with your **ExampleViewController**.

Then you need to embed your first controller with navigation controller. 
 [To add navigation controller -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080320/embed-navigationcontroller-in-container-view)

[image: Embed navigation option]

Comment: it is nil :( But I don't really get how I can embed my vc with a navigation controller.

Comment: Go to story board. Select your controller in storyboard. Then go to editor and embed i navigation controller. Attaching screenshot in answer.

Comment: should I do this for both of them?

Comment: Only for the first view controller.

Comment: do I have to change anything else? Or somehow link it with the second ViewController?

Comment: No, when you call <pre> self.navigationController?.pushViewController(B, animated: true) <code> in A viewcontroller then same navigation can be used for B as well because navigation manages a  view controller stack and when we push a nnew view controller, navigation pushes the new VC into that stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202202/discussion-between-chris-and-mohit-mangla).